# Twiiter Api find error

Tags: android, twitter

m using twitter api and find the error how to resolve it and i m using lib folder and 4 lib file in this folder but fin in error ..please help me out bellow error Notification:

Could not find class `'twitter4j.http.AccessToken'`, referenced from method `

```
public void updateLoginStatus() {

        loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
    }
```

here crash my apps and any one provide new turorial or solution of twiiter Integration..please help me out